# Robot Framework does not recognize custom library's class (class name and filename are the same)

Tags: python, robotframework

Basic problem is that although the library file name and the class name are the same (as the Robot Framework manual advice), the `Library    PywinautoLibrary` import does not find the class keywords. `Library    PywinautoLibrary.PywinautoLibrary` does work however.

I know that the Robot Framework Python file cannot have both class and static funtions, so there are no static functions.

I have made custom **pip** installable wheel file with this setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='robotframework-pywinautolibrary',
    description='Robot Framework wrapper for pywinauto',
    version='1.0',
    classifiers=['Programming Language :: Python :: >=3.6'],
    package_dir={'' : 'src'},
    packages=['PywinautoLibrary'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['pywinauto>=0.6.6'],
    author='****',
    author_email='****',
)
```

The only other Python package file is empty `__init__.py`
Then my `PywinautoLibrary.py` starts like this:

```
#LIBRARY DEFINITIONS-----------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 15
DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 0.5

#Kwargs definitions
TIMEOUT = 'timeout'
RETRY_INTERVAL = 'retry_interval'
UNIQUE_ID = 'unique_id'
INIT_TEXT = 'init_text'
WINDOW_GETTER = 'window_getter'
WINDOW_KWARGS = 'window_kwargs'
USER_TIMEOUT = 'user_timeout'
COMPARE_FUNCTION = 'compare_func'

#Props definitions
FONTS_KEY = 'fonts'
RECTANGE_KEY = 'rectangle'
CLIENT_RECTS_KEY = 'client_rects'


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


class PywinautoLibrary:

def __init__(self):
   ...
```

Python installation directory looks like this:

```
(python32_env) PS C:\python32_env\lib\site-packages\PywinautoLibrary>    


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8.5.2019     10.36                __pycache__
-a----         8.5.2019     10.36          23088 PywinautoLibrary.py
-a----         8.5.2019     10.36              0 __init__.py
```

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: try ``from PywinautoLibrary.PywinautoLibrary import PywinautoLibrary`` in ``__init__.py``

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you explain what the problem was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Library    PywinautoLibrary` you say to import PywinautoLibrary but say nothing about the class you want to use from that file because `__init__.py` is empty. Importing `Library    PywinautoLibrary.PywinautoLibrary` you import the `PywinautoLibrary` class from that library and that is why it works.

So `__init__.py` must contain at least the following:

```
from PywinautoLibrary.PywinautoLibrary import PywinautoLibrary
```

It imports the `PywinautoLibrary` class from the PywinautoLibrary module and keywords are visible.

Comment: I think I confused the importing of regular ```.py``` file with the ```Library``` Keyword to importing an actual library.